# Query custom type posts by array of IDs

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I can't seem to get `post__in` to work with custom post types. Is this true? What's the alternative?

```
$args = array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'tf_events', 'duka' ), 
   'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'showposts' => -1, 
   'post__in' => explode(',',$mtheme_featured) );
query_posts($args);
```

`$mtheme_featured` has two ids separated by commas, one post and one tf_event; only the post is shown.

Comment: This most likely isn't what's causing your problem, but it should be `'posts_per_page'` instead of `'showposts'`. `'showposts'` is for the `get_posts()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said the post type is called 'tf_event', but in the 'post_type' array it's 'tf_events'.

Comment: it's tf-events. but i'll double check.

Comment: i added a duka post id. 'post' is showing; duka and tf_events not.

Comment: ok. something is going on with tf_events; duka is showing.

Comment: so `post__in` does work with custom post types! my bad.